# Calling R function with parameters from Scala using JVMR

Tags: r, scala

I am using jvmr to run R in Scala. I am not sure how to call a R function from scala by passing the parameters.

Below attached the scala file:

```
package org.scala.rtest

import org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala

object RIntegration {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val R = RInScala()
       R>"""
            score.sentiment = function (sentences, pos.words,neg.words, .progress='none')
                {
                    require(plyr)
                    require(stringr)

                    scores =  laply(sentences, function(sentence,pos.words,neg.words){

                sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]','',sentence)
                sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]','',sentence)
                sentence = gsub('\\d+','',sentence)
                sentence = tolower(sentence)

                word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+')
                words = unlist(word.list)

                pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)

                neg.matches = match(words, neg.words)

                pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)

                neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)

                score = sum(pos.matches) - sum (neg.matches)

                return(score)

              },pos.words, neg.words, .progress = .progress)

              scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)

              return(scores.df)

            } 

       pos_words = scan("C:\\Users\\servicelyadmin\\Downloads\\opinion-lexicon-English\\positive-words.txt",what="character",comment.char=";")
       neg_words = scan("C:\\Users\\servicelyadmin\\Downloads\\opinion-lexicon-English\\negative-words.txt",what="character",comment.char=";")
       tweetsdata = scan("C:\\Users\\servicelyadmin\\Downloads\\opinion-lexicon-English\\twitterstream1.txt",what="character")
       analysis = score.sentiment(tweetsdata,pos_words,neg_words)

       """
       println(R.capture("analysis"))

        }
}
```

This code above works perfectly fine and prints the output. but i Need to move the function call outside the prompt like below by passing in the values to the function. I am not sure how to achieve this.

```
  val pos_words = R.apply("scan('positive-words.txt',what='character',comment.char=';')")
       val neg_words = R.apply("scan('negative-words.txt',what='character',comment.char=';')")
       val tweetsdata = R.apply("scan('twitterstream1.txt',what='character')")
       val analysis = R.eval("score.sentiment('tweetsdata','pos_words','neg_words')")
println(R.capture("analysis"))
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Pawan Venugopal

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with jvmr.

```
package org.scala.rtest

import org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala

object RIntegration {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val R = RInScala()
       R>"""
            require(sparkR)

            score.sentiment = function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words, .progress='none')
                {
                  require(plyr)
                  require(stringr)


                  scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words) {

                    # clean up sentences with R's regex-driven global substitute, gsub():

                    sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence, ignore.case=T)

                    sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence, ignore.case=T)

                    sentence = gsub('\\d+', '', sentence, ignore.case=T)

                    # and convert to lower case:

                    sentence = tolower(sentence)

                    # split into words. str_split is in the stringr package

                    word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+')

                    # sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much

                    words = unlist(word.list)

                    # compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms

                    pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)
                    neg.matches = match(words, neg.words)

                    # match() returns the position of the matched term or NA
                    # we just want a TRUE/FALSE:

                    pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)

                    neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)

                    # and conveniently enough, TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():

                    score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)

                    return(score)

                  }, pos.words, neg.words, .progress=.progress )
                  scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)
                  return(scores.df)
                } 


       """

        R(" x <- scan('positive-words.txt',what='character',comment.char=';')")
        R(" y <- scan('negative-words.txt',what='character',comment.char=';')")
        R(" z <- scan('twitterstream1.txt', what='character' )")

        R.eval("df <- score.sentiment(z,x,y)")  
        println(R.capture("df"))

        }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to replicate the same but how do I install `jvmr` ? Is there any `pom.xml` or any `.jar` file for this ?